# ​[bidirectional] is going in two directions

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[bidirectional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bidirectional) can have at least two meanings:

1. Data structures: [Does Java have a HashMap with reverse lookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670038/does-java-have-a-hashmap-with-reverse-lookup)
2. Text direction: [multilingual websites and rtl direction - best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394975/multilingual-websites-and-rtl-direction-best-practices)

This isn't surprising, considering that "bidirectional" doesn't mean much by itself - it's a meta tag.

The first one should probably use [bidirectional-relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bidirectional-relation), the second [bidi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bidi).

Edit:

Other meanings:

1. Bidirectional breadth-first search: [Termination Criteria for Bidirectional Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253413/termination-criteria-for-bidirectional-search)
2. Bidirectional sockets (should tag as [sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sockets)): [How do I establish a bidirectional SSH Tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983795/how-do-i-establish-a-bidirectional-ssh-tunnel)
3. Bidirectional replication: [Couchdb conflict resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605870/couchdb-conflict-resolution)
4. Invertible functions (probably should be untagged): [How to convert RGB -> YUV -> RGB (both ways)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892346/how-to-convert-rgb-yuv-rgb-both-ways)

Unclear:

1. [Algorithm to find subset within two sets of integers whose sums match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443712/algorithm-to-find-subset-within-two-sets-of-integers-whose-sums-match)

Comment: The first idea that came to me was LPT ports. I'm old...

Comment: Both bidirectional and bidirectional-relation don't have a wikis either.  Only 225 questions under bidirectional, so yes, update the wiki on bidirection-relation to make it specific to data structures and retag bidirectional as appropriate and watch bidirectional burn

Comment: In the first case, bijective is actually a more precise term.

Comment: I found at least 4 more meanings

Comment: This is definitely one of the better tag puns I've seen here.